# The div in my index page is not visible and/or showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a personal webpage and, in the index i want to put some divs in front of the background image that is below the navigation bar. Any other code corrections are welcome as i'm learning to make webpages.

I can't get them to show up even ater deleting the background image.

html:

```
<body>
<div class="vista">
    <div>
        <header>
            <a href="./index.html" class="cabecera">
                <p class="titulo">Bienvenido a PS2 HACKS</p>
                <img src="./imgs/1688px-PS2-Fat-Console-Set.png" alt="Foto de una PS2" class="logo">
            </a>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <a href="./prereq.html" class="links">Pre-requisitos</a>
            <a href="./descargas.html" class="links">Descargas</a>
            <a href="./freedvdbootcomp.html" class="links">Compatibilidad FreeDVDBoot</a>
            <a href="./juegos.html" class="links">Top 10 juegos PS2</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="inicio">
        <div id="div1">
            
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <div class="cuadros"></div>
            <div class="cuadros"></div>
            <div class="cuadros"></div>
            <div class="cuadros"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.inicio {
height: 85vh;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("./imgs/PS2-Alfabetajuega.webp");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 80%;
background-position: center;
}

#div1 {
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
color: #1eff00;
}

#div2 {
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your example *does* work. The DIVs don't show up in the browser, because your child-divs of #div1 and #div don't have content (yet). Maybe you left out some parts, but if i put content in those divs, they do appear.

I'm just guessing: Maybe you were expecting seeing two squares in the defined colors? Well, try using `background-color` instead of `color`.

But maybe I got you wrong and you already have content in #div1 and #div2 - if this the case I'd assume, that there's some other CSS involved.

I can recommend you get familiar with Chrome or Firefox Dev Tools. This will allows you to inspect your HTML elements in the browser and see all CSS applied to them.

Comment: yes, it was definetly the background-color thing, thanks so much, such an embarrasing mistake